# Export-CSV formatting carriage returns

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I'm retrieving information from the active directory but when I try to export it with `Export-CSV` there are some issues with the carriage returns. It's starting a new line in the CSV-file for each return it finds, while it should actually stay on the current line.

```
$User = Get-ADUser Bob -Properties *
Display name    : Bob Smith
Notes           : Line 1
                  Line 2
                  Line 3
E-mail          : Bob.Smith@company.com

$User | Export-CSV 'C:\file.csv'
Display name, Notes, E-mail
Bob Smith, Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Bob.Smith@company.com
```

How can I have the following output?

```
$User | Export-CSV 'C:\file.csv'
Display name, Notes, E-mail
Bob Smith, Line 1 Line 2 Line 3, Bob.Smith@company.com
```

I've tried with encoding, other delimiters, .. Can't really figure this one out.

**Solution**

```
$User | Select 'Display Name', @{l='Notes';e={$_.Notes -replace "`n"," "}}, E-mail | Export-Csv 'C:\file.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are having trouble with inserted CR/LF with a specific field you can always perform a `-join` on Notes in an expression at a Select operator. Something like:

```
$User | Select DisplayName, @{l='Notes';e={$_.Notes -join ", "}}, Email | Export-Csv 'C:\files.csv'
```

That will output the desired output.

If you are having the issue with multiple fields then it gets a bit more complicated as far as how I'd solve it (by reproducing the object as a custom object recreating all the fields, and processing their values with -join or replacing "`n" with ', ')

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked great :) I used the `-replace` method as you suggested. OP updated with the **solution**.

Answer (score 0):

The result you get schould be correct because it's seperatet by ",". If you import the csv by "Import-Csv" you get the correct data. The problem is the property "Notes". There are line breaks. Exclude the notes ore replace ``r`n (line break) with "$null".

Answer (score 0):

Really old thread but after extensive Googling couldn't still find no answer, but stumbled on the right answer by myself and decided to share.
Problem was that output CSV was having a line break.

`$resultti = $result.computername -join " " | Out-String`

`$resultti | Export-Csv -Path $outfile -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8`

And out-put CSV looked like "-character always on the next line:

"Name";"Email";"Samaccountname";"Workstations"

"Pete";"pete@xx.fi";"pete";"W7DT1335 W7LT1812

"

"Anne";"anne@xx.fi";"anne";"W7DT13565 W7LT1612

"

"Anton";"Anton@xx.fi";"anton";"W7DT1345 W7LT1752

"

This didn't end up well with replace either.

```
$resultti = $resultti.Replace("`n","x")
```

--> CSV looked like:

"Name";"Email";"Samaccountname";"Workstations"
"Pete";"pete@xx.fi";"pete";"W7DT1335 W7LT1812

x"

"Anne";"anne@xx.fi";"anne";"W7DT13565 W7LT1612

x"

"Anton";"Anton@xx.fi";"anton";"W7DT1345 W7LT1752

x"

Solution for me was to stream out-string like this:
`$resultti = $result.computername -join " " | Out-String -Stream`

And CSV looked after that nice.

"Name";"Email";"Samaccountname";"Workstations"

"Pete";"pete@xx.fi";"pete";"W7DT1335 W7LT1812"

"Anne";"anne@xx.fi";"anne";"W7DT13565 W7LT1612"

"Anton";"Anton@xx.fi";"anton";"W7DT1345 W7LT1752"